# Difference between homeomorphism between open intervals and closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I have an exercise that asks to show that:
(i) two closed bounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphics;
(ii) two open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphics.

I began naturally by (i), trying to show a mapping that is a homeomorphism between the two intervals. I tried to construct a linear mapping
\begin{align}
f : [a,b] &\rightarrow [c,d] \\
x &\mapsto (\frac{d-c}{b-a})x+ (c-a\frac{d-c}{b-a})
\end{align}
which is clearly inversible and bijective.
But then I got to (ii) and I don't know what is the difference of considering open intervals instead of closed, bounded ones. Is what I am doing right? What is the difference between the two cases?

Comment: The mapping rule itself is the same, but the crucial difference is that you're mapping $[a,b]$ homeomorphically onto $[c,d]$ in the first case (i.e. *both* of the intervals are closed) and $(a,b)$ homeomorphically onto $(c,d)$ in the second (i.e. *both* of the intervals are open). If you were to "mix" the open and the closed sets, i.e. if you wanted to construct a homeomorphism between $(a,b)$ and $[c,d]$, you would not be able to do it.

Comment: Thank you. But why I would not be able to "mix" open and closed intervals?
Plus, I have just thought that in the open case, the intervals don't need to be bounded. So I would have more cases, for example, mapping the whole $\mathbb{R}$ onto an open set $(a,b)$.

Comment: Because homeomorphisms map open sets to open sets, and closed sets to closed sets. To see this, recall that the preimage of an open set under a continuous function is open, and that homeomorphisms have continuous inverses by definition. EDIT: To get you started on the unbounded case, consider the $\arctan$ function.

Comment: a = b is a special case.